# How to execute mongodb commands inside the bash script

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, kubernetes, containers

I'm trying to run mongo commands through my bash script file.

I have sample.sh -- run with ./sample.sh

I want to run below command inside my sample.sh file. It is bash script.
I want to mongo commands run inside the file, not inside the shell.

```
kubectl exec $mongoPodName -c mongo-mongodb -- mongo db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"123456",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})
```

I get the error below :

```
./generate-service-dbs.sh: line 37: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./generate-service-dbs.sh: line 37: `kubectl exec $mongoPodName -c mongo-mongodb -- mongo db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"123456",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you have to run command with `--eval`?

```bash
kubectl exec $mongoPodName -c mongo-mongodb -- mongo --eval 'db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"123456",roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]})'
```

Comment: I try --eval for this command ``` kubectl exec $mongoPodName -c mongo-mongodb -- mongo --eval 'use myTest' ``` . It has error : ``` 2020-08-18T22:31:53.745+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell eval):1:4 ```

Comment: I need to create mongodbs with user and roles from *.ini files, so i should run multi-line mongo commands within my  sample.sh file, but i have many errors.

Comment: I am afraid I am not too familiar with mongodb but you should able to run a few command in a .js file. Please see this reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-arg-file-js

Comment: We need to use double quotes (") instead of single quotes here. I tested with both cases, and the one which works is with single quotes. ```kubectl exec $mongoPodName -c mongo-mongodb -- mongo --eval "db.createUser({user:\"admin\",pwd:\"123456\",roles:[{role:\"root\",db:\"admin\"}]});"```